# Custom URL Scheme Error : This app is not allowed to query for scheme

Tags: ios, swift, communication-protocol

I have 2 apps , one client and one server. I am trying interapp communication between ios apps using URL schemes

( I have refered to this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app  as guideline )

This is the plist for client end

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.test.serverendapp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>serverendapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.test.serverendapp</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Code for iOS end

```
@IBAction func tapToClient(){
        let urlsrting = "com.test.serverEndApp://requestInfo?userID='22'"
        let url = URL(string: urlsrting)!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (success) in
                    print(" this is \(success)")
                }

            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }else{

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
                "There is no such server app here", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

The server end

plist

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.test.clientendapp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>clientendapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.test.clientendapp</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

code

```
 @IBAction func tapToServer(){
        let urlsrting = "com.test.clientEndApp://provideInfo?username='Debanjan'"
        let url = URL(string: urlsrting)!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (success) in
                    print(" this is \(success)")
                }

            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }else{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message:
                "There is no such client app here", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

All I get from either of them is

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.test.clientEndApp://provideInfo?username='Debanjan'" - error:
>   "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.test.clientendapp"
>
> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.test.serverEndApp://requestInfo?userID='22'" - error: "This app
>   is not allowed to query for scheme com.test.serverendapp"

I have followed all the steps and yet am being in this rut . Help me out to realise what am I doing wrong

I am running it on iPhone 8 iOS 12.2 simulator, on xcode 12.2

Comment: Run on device, not simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it in opposite way if you register:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>com.test.clientEndApp</string>
</array>
```

You should be calling this scheme

```
let urlsrting = "com.test.clientEndApp://provideInfo?username='Debanjan'"
```

An you were missing `com.test.` from your `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Comment: I just did that. It still gives me the error. Please check on the updated plists.

Comment: what you did? you still call different url than scheme you register there is a deifference between: `com.test.clientEndApp` and `clientEndApp`

Comment: I changed the url scheme as you mentioned for client and server app. Client App now has the serverendapp scheme, server has clientendapp scheme

Comment: Yeah, even if the com.test prefix is added , it still doesn't work. What I understood from your point, client app should point to serverapp's url scheme and vice versa. I did that and ran the project. Cleaned up my simulator as well

Comment: It does not look like you have tried it, and error is completely the same and you are 100% sure that schemes ar set everywhere exactly the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201256/discussion-between-debanjan-chakraborty-and-lu).

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @Lu_, for pointing out my mistakes

Points :
1. The client app will have the scheme for the server app and vice versa
2. The LS should have a whole name and no such com.test or what nots